# Mudblazor carousel not scaling on page resize

Tags: html, css, mudblazor

Using a MudImage, you can set `Fluid="true"` and see the image scale perfectly, no matter if you are on mobile, desktop, or resizing the window.  It keeps aspect ratio and doesn't push out text below it.  Here is an example - just hit play, then drag the divider left to right to see how nicely everything keeps together: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuQduemTUalxoBpL

As soon as I put it in a MudCarousel, it loses this ability.  The carousel forces me to set a Style with a height, for example Style="min-height:600px; `width:100%;`.  This looks good on desktop, but horrible on mobile.  If I change to 150px, it looks great on mobile and horrible on desktop.  If I leave height off, it breaks in a different way.  Here is that example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOGRaSGyaznuVqWV

Is it possible to get the carousel with images working like normal fluid images?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you found a solution to make the carousel responsive?